# How can I find the coefficients of the next recursive symbolic function?

Tags: symbolic, recursion, difference-equations

I have the following function
$$
f(x+3k) = -mf(x+2k)+f(x)
$$.
If we get $x=x+k$, then
$$
f(x+4k) = -mf(x+3k)+f(x+k) = m^2f(x+2k)+f(x+k)-mf(x)
$$. Also we obtain the coefficients of the final functions, $\{ f(x+2k),f(x+k),f(x)\}$, as $\{m^2,1,-m\}$. How can I find for the coefficients of the functions, $\{ f(x+2k),f(x+k),f(x) \}$,  for the cases $\{x=x+2k, x=x+3k, \ldots \}$ by using Mathematica.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The recurrence relation can be represented by

```
f[0] = f0; f[1] = f1; f[2] = f2; f[n_] := f[n] = Simplify[-m f[n - 1] + f[n - 3]]
```

based on which, the coefficients of `{f2, f1, f0}` for `n = 4` are given by

```
CoefficientArrays[f[4], {f2, f1, f0}][[2]] // Normal
(* {m^2, 1, -m} *)
```

which agrees with the results predicted in the question.  Coefficients for larger values of `n` are obtained similarly.  For instance

```
CoefficientArrays[f[5], {f2, f1, f0}][[2]] // Normal
(* {1 - m^3, -m, m^2} *)

CoefficientArrays[f[25], {f2, f1, f0}][[2]] // Normal
(* {36 m^2 - 462 m^5 + 1287 m^8 - 1365 m^11 + 680 m^14 - 171 m^17 + 21 m^20 - m^23, 
    1 - 84 m^3 + 462 m^6 - 715 m^9 + 455 m^12 - 136 m^15 + 19 m^18 - m^21, 
    -8 m + 210 m^4 - 792 m^7 + 1001 m^10 - 560 m^13 + 153 m^16 - 20 m^19 + m^22} *)
```

**Improved Timing**

In a comment below, [Mr. Wizard](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/121/mr-wizard) suggested using `Factor` instead of `Simplify` in the definition of `f[n]`.  This modification reduces `AbsoluteTiming` from 4.2 sec to 0.12 sec for `f[100]`.  Note that not using either make the computation prohibitively slow and memory-intensive.

Comment: Thank you @bbgodfrey. I think your code would be slow for higher order indexes. How can I find the (?) coefficients in the equation $f(x+5k)=-mf(x+4k)+f(x+2k)=?f(x+2k)+ ?f(x+k) + ?f(x)$.

Comment: @drxy  My revision should work better, at least for moderate `n`.

Comment: @drxy and bbgodfrey, I think you will find that `Factor` is a better choice than `Simplify` here; on my system (v10.1) the function with `Simplify` takes 9.8 seconds, whereas after substituting `Factor` it takes only 0.187 second.  The expression is fractionally longer but I don't think it will matter for your application.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard  Right, you are.  `f[100]` takes about 4 sec with `Simplify` and only 3% of that with `Factor`.  I shall modify my answer, citing your contribution.  Thanks.

Comment: I meant to say my timings were for `f[150]` but I somehow forgot that.  You're welcome, and thank you.

Comment: @bbgodfrey,@Mr.Wizard Thank you. You have done of course what I want ...

Answer (score 4):

A slick reformulation of bbgodfrey's answer is to recognize that the required computation is equivalent to evaluating an appropriate matrix power:

```
With[{n = 5},
     MatrixPower[{{-m, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 1}, {1, 0, 0}}, n - 2, {1, 0, 0}]] // Simplify
   {1 - m^3, -m, m^2}

With[{n = 25},
     MatrixPower[{{-m, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 1}, {1, 0, 0}}, n - 2, {1, 0, 0}]] // Simplify
   {-m^2 (-36 + 462 m^3 - 1287 m^6 + 1365 m^9 - 680 m^12 + 171 m^15 - 21 m^18 + m^21), 
    1 - 84 m^3 + 462 m^6 - 715 m^9 + 455 m^12 - 136 m^15 + 19 m^18 - m^21,
    m (-8 + 210 m^3 - 792 m^6 + 1001 m^9 - 560 m^12 + 153 m^15 - 20 m^18 + m^21)}
```

Note that I have explicitly used the *action form* of `MatrixPower[]`, since we are only interested in a single column, and not the whole matrix.